# How JavaScript regex work on this spinal case sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following JavaScript fucntion :

```js
function spinalCase(str) {
  str = str.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2');
  console.log(str);
}

spinalCase('thisIsSpinalTapIp');
```

Now it's showing me:

> this Is Spinal Tap Ip

I can't understand how it identifies the **space()** and why it's using **2 regular expressions** inside the **replace** function. Can you break it down please?

***Note: the goal of this function is to get the spinal case sentence.***

Comment: the regex parses every occurrance of a sequence of a lowercase and an uppercase letter, stores the lowercase one in `$1` and the uppercase one in `$2`... then it replaces `$1$2` with `$1 $2`, eg inserts a space

Comment: There is only one regex with 2 capture groups and it inserts space between a lowercase and uppercase letter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's break it down:

`([a-z])` is matching a lowercase letter

`([A-Z])` is matching for an uppercase letter

`/([a-z])([A-Z])/g` combine is matching for lowercase followed by an upperCase letter with the global flag that will match for all these occurrences.

When such occurrences are found they are getting replaced by $1 $2
(here $1 is group one lowercase letter and $2 is group 2 uppercase letter separated by a space).

Now let see how it work for **thisIsSpinalTapIp**

The above regex will match **sI**, **sS**, **lT**, and **pI**

and replace them with **s I**, **s S**, **l T**,  and **p I**

so the string become **this Is Spinal Tap Ip**

This link will help you to visualize it [regex](https://regex101.com/r/uXT2td/1)

Comment: Great explanation :)

Comment: So does it replace all the small letter by capital letter?

Comment: @creativeartbd It doesn't replace a small letter with capital one. Instead, it replaces the combination of a small and capital letter by adding a space between them e.g. `iT` will be replaced by `i T`

Comment: well, then how it's showing this result `this Is Spinal Tap Ip` ?

Answer (score 2):

the regex parses every occurrance of a sequence of a lowercase and an uppercase letter, stores the lowercase one in `$1` and the uppercase one in `$2`... then it replaces `$1$2` with `$1 $2`, eg inserts a space.

following match:

> thi**sIsS**pina**lT**a**pI**p

so you'd have the collection `['sI','sS','lT','pI']` where the spaces will be added in between

Answer (score 0):

You created two groups name $1 and $2 by parentheses in the RegEx.
$1 and $2 refers to strings matched by those groups.

and those strings will replace $1 and $2 in the second parameter of String.replace.

every groups' name is like $Number, the number will increase by the sequence of parentheses in the Regex.